# Can you bind multiple LineSeries to an oxyplot in WPF using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-core, oxyplot

I am trying to plot multiple `LineSeries` elements in one `<oxy:PlotView />` element in WPF using C# in Oxyplot where I am using the MVVM pattern. Say I have the (hypothetical) situation that I am tracking cars with a position as a function of time. Say I have the following files:

- Model

  - Car.cs
- View

  - DisplayView.xaml
  - DisplayView.xaml.cs
- ViewModel

  - DisplayViewModel.cs

On initialization I create three car elements (in `DisplayViewModel.cs` : `Cars = new List<Car>{ new Car(), ...};`) with their corresponding displacement vs. time data `PlotData = new List<DataPoint>{ new DataPoint(0,1), new DataPoint(1,4), ...};` and `CarName`.

**DisplayView.xaml (1):**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <oxy:Plot Title="{Binding CarName}" Height="400" Width="500">
                    <oxy:Plot.Series>
                        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlotData}"/>
                    </oxy:Plot.Series>
                </oxy:Plot>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This works as expected. It shows a `<ListBox />` with the three (separate) graphs. However this is not what I am trying to achieve. I would like to do something like the following:

**DisplayView.xaml (2):**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CarName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This displays the three individual car names as is expected, so I know I have the data source connected correctly. However, wrapping this `<ItemsControl>...</ItemsControl>` element with `<oxy:Plot><oxy:Plot.Series>...</oxy:Plot.Series></oxy:Plot>` and changing the `<TextBlock />` element to a `<oxy:LineSeries />` element and binding its `ItemsSource` property to the earlier mentioned `DataPoint` field yields the errors `` A value of type 'ItemsControl' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'collection`1'. `` and `The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "Series".`.

**DisplayView.xaml (doesn't work):**

```
<oxy:Plot Title="Displacement plot">
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlotData}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

I am new to the MVVM pattern - and C# and WPF programming in general - and I see the `DisplayView.xaml.cs` code-behind file needs to be empty. I can get the three LineSeries to display in one graph when using the code behind, but I am trying to utilize the power of MVVM. Can someone give me pointers on how I *should* fix this? I am just not experienced enough (yet) to play around with the code, so some explanation would be appreciated. What files do I need to add, what methods do I need to create and where do I create these? Is this even possible in the way I envision?

Kind regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I grasp the concept (after writing down my thoughts and questions in this post), so I am answering my own question. In `DisplayView.xaml` I added a `<PlotView />` as such: `<oxy:PlotView x:Name="DisplayPlotView" Model="{Binding PlotModel}" />`. I also created a `PlotModel` in `DisplayViewModel.cs`, which is fine by the MVVM-pattern, as far as I understand. I loop through `Cars` to add the different series by doing:

```
foreach(Car car in Cars)
    {
        PlotModel.Series.Add(car.PlotData);
    }
```

Where I now made the `PlotData` a `LineSeries` in the `Car.cs`. This shows the three lines in one graph.